# React-select does not render data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

I'm trying to use `react-select` to make a simple dropdown menu, with values from public API. 
However, even though the fetch from API appears to be working correctly (`console.log()` shows the desired data), there are no options in the dropdown selection.

I've tried following this thread [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47672117/react-select-how-to-show-iterate-through-data-from-api-call-in-option-instea)

But since I wanted to use hooks, I had to make some changes.

I used the third approach from the top comment in the thread (the one where you pass `labelKey` and `valueKey` as a prop, instead of creating a new array), but the dropdown is just full of empty fields.

Here's an example of the data from API

```
"results:[
 {"name":"Algeria","code":"DZ","cities":1,"locations":1,"count":1149},
 {"name":"Andorra","code":"AD","cities":2,"locations":3,"count":80963},
 {"name":"Argentina","code":"AR","cities":1,"locations":4,"count":14976}
]
```

And here's the code for the actual function

```
function SearchBar(props) {
  const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([]);

  function handleChange(e) {
    props.setCountryName(e.value);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      async function FetchData() {
        fetch(`https://api.openaq.org/v1/countries?limit=300`, {mode: 'cors'})
          .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
            (result) => {
              setOptions(result.results)
            })
          }   
          FetchData()   
      }
    ,[])  

    console.log(options);

  return(
    <Select
    className='react-select-container'
    placeholder="Choose country" 
    onChange={handleChange}
    labelKey="name"
    valueKey="code"
    options={options}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `react-select` you need to tell which one the `label` and which is the `value`. If you do not have explicitly `label` and `value` in the `options` array.

```
<Select
    className='react-select-container'
    placeholder="Choose country" 
    onChange={handleChange}
    labelKey="name"
    valueKey="code"
    getOptionLabel={option => {
          return option.name;
        }}
    getOptionValue={option => {
          return option.code;
        }}
    options={options}
 />
```

Comment: That did it, thank you!
The answer from the question I linked made me think that's what `labelKey` and `valueKey` are for.
Now that I've checked, those props are not even in the documentation. 
Was there some change in `react-select` or I didn't understand something?

Comment: @JarekN Check the lastest docs you will see the changes I'm not sure about `labelKey` and `valueKey` never used it before. Make sure you Select the answer if it worked for you helps other people. Thanks!.